# due to backslash in apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, redirect

```
RewriteRule ^/colleges/([A-Za-z0-9-.']+)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /ShowMasterdashboard.do?cn=$1&institutionId=$2 [PT,NC,L]
```

server attempt to load css and js from colleges/css/*.css and colleges/js/*.js,so page look ugly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash before script/css location:

`<script src="/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

instead of

`<script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`